# getting value using explode

Tags: php

I am trying to parse following string...

```
IN.Tags.Share({"count":180,"url":"http://domain.org"}
```

is my following approach correct to get the value of count?

```
$str = 'IN.Tags.Share({"count":180,"url":"http://domain.org"}';
$data = explode(':', $str);
$val = explode(',', $data[1]);
return $val[0];
```

Or is there any better way to handling this type of strings? I think it could be done using regex as well.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If course I'm not sure if your format will be constant, but part of your string looks like JSON. If always like this, you could do:

```
 $str = str_replace('IN.Tags.Share(', '', $str);
 $values = json_decode($str);
 echo $values->count;
```

Comment: also it should be `echo $values->count;` as json_decode() returns an object in this case.

Comment: Right. Fixed, but I believe you could have edited that as well :)

Comment: True, but now you'll remember better :) (removed the -1 too as you've fixed it)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest pulling out the JSON by applying this regex to the string: `IN\.Tags\.Share\((.*)\`. Pull out the first group, and use `json_decode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

That way, you can directly access the data. It will support complex data structures as well.